# How to make count and search in a single query on same table on laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
public function getDeleteQuote($quote_id)
{
    $quote = Quote::find($quote_id);
    $author_id = $quote->author_id;
    $total_quote = DB::table('quotes')->where('author_id' , $author_id)->count();
    $author_deleted = false;

    if($total_quote === 1)
    {
        $auth_deleted = DB::table('authors')->where('id' , $author_id)->delete();
        $author_deleted = true;
    }
    $quote->delete();
    $msg = $author_deleted ? 'Quote And Author Deleted !' : 'Quote Deleted !' ;
    return redirect()->route('home')->with([
        'success' => $msg 
    ]);
}
```

In first 3 lines i am using two search on same table one for find quote_id and other for counting how much quote in same author . But i want to do this only a single query . How can i do that ?

Comment: Put all the code aside. Instead, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements and a desired result

Comment: you can probably do this a lot better with relationships and also using cascade delete so on delete remove associated author too, etc but needs a bit more to help arrive at what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have Quote model that refers to 'quotes' table and Author model associated with 'authors' table, specify the relationship in the Quote Class.

```
class Quote{

    /*... other code here */

    public function authors(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Author');
    }
}
```

Then you can store the query builder in a variable calling the relationship function and use it.

```
public function getDeleteQuote($quote_id)
{
    //Get The Quote Object
    $quote = Quote::find($quote_id);

    //Get the query builder from relationship and store in a variable
    $quote_query = $quote->authors();

    //Delete authors with condition
    $author_deleted = ($quote_query->count() === 1) ? $quote_query->delete() : false;

    //Delete the Quote
    $quote->delete();

    $msg = $author_deleted ? 'Quote And Author Deleted !' : 'Quote Deleted !' ;
    return redirect()->route('home')->with([
        'success' => $msg 
    ]);
}
```

P.S. if the relation is One-to-one set `$this->hasOne('App\Author');`

Comment: yeah thank u i have a wrong with my databse relation

Comment: if u describe how Quote model works and establish relation with author modals then i will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

will try and see if this can work:

Here is say the Quote model with the authors relationship:

```
class Quote extends Model
{
    /**
     * get the associated author for the quote
     */
    public function authors(){
       return $this->hasOne(Author::class);
    }

}
```

The find the quote with its author etc:

```
public function getDeleteQuote($quote_id)
{
    $quote = Quote::findOrFail($quote_id)->with('authors');

    if($quote->authors->count() > 0){
      $author_deleted = $quote->authors->delete();
    }

    $quote->delete();

    return route('home')->with('success' => ($author_deleted) ? 'Quote And Author Deleted !' : 'Quote Deleted !');
}
```

Nothing to test on so not sure if it will display issues etc as dependant on your set up etc, but look up relationships etc but hopefully might help.

Comment: Thank u Mr. Simon Davies , my problem will be solved , but i am greatful if u describe me how this can be work .... 

    if($quote->authors->count() > 0){
          $author_deleted = $quote->authors->delete();
    }

Comment: not sure if this is wat u want but it checks to see if the authors count is bigger than 0 so it has some then attempts to delete them returning a boolean 0 or 1 so true or false, to the $author_deleted var., hope this helps :-)

Comment: yeah i want that,  but i want to know how $quote->authors->count() works?

Comment: it should get the results of the authors for the quote, and return a count of how many there are, so it could be 0,1 or more, if thats not working you could also try count($quote->authors) etc, similar to a query count `SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE ???;` something like that